# Remote Method Invocation Phonegap and C#

Tags: c#, cordova

I'd like to let my app on Phonegap provoke methods in my C# app. I know I have to run a server on the PC to let the app connect to the PC via local WiFi. But how do I get the Phonegap app to invoke the methods? Are there any plugins for this or do I can use a way more "easy" technique to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to send or get data from your phone app to or from your pc/server?

If that is the case, the easiest solution would be a REST Web API on the server side(your PC), and then just do standard REST HTTP requests to your API from your phone app. A request could be a GET if you want your API to serve data to your phone app, or a POST if you'd like to send something to your API.

I'm not familiar with Phonegap but if you're using jQuery in your app you could call your api roughly like this to get, for example, all products:

```
$.get( "http://my-pc/api/products/", function( data ) {
   alert( data );
});
```

I highly recommend ASP.NET Web API, [Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api)

As well as looking into the basic principles of REST, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)